# Book reccomendations for Pertubation Theory?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, books

I'm sorry if this is an inappropriate place to ask this, but I'm still trying to get the hang of this site. So my book is Thomas Engel and Philip Reid Physical Chemistry $3^{rd}$  ed. I'm on the Chapter 17: "Commuting and Non-commuting Operators and the Surprising Consequences of Entanglement

However, it is missing the Chapter on Perturbation Theory, which I was told should've been where chapter 18 is. Instead of Ch. 18, we have A Quantum Mechanical Model for the
Vibration and Rotation of Molecules. Where are some good sources for Pertubation Theory that would have this?

Comment: My personal suggestion is to skip the "physical chemistry" books and go straight to the "physics" books, or the "quantum mechanics" books. Griffiths was my favourite when I started.

Comment: Cohen-Tannoudji is recommended in the duplicate, it's a standard text for QM too.